# Binary Addition using a carry

Tags: python, binary, addition

Im trying to add two binary numbers without converting the two numbers, S and T, into a base 10,using recursion and I'm having difficulty incorporating the carry into the code. Also, I'm not exactly sure what to do if one binary number is longer than the other.

```
def addB(S,T):
  '''adds binary number without converting to base 10'''
  def addBhelper(S,T,carry):
    if S=='' and T=='':
        return ''
    if S[-1] + T[-1]+carry==0:
        return addBhelper(S[:-1],T[:-1],0) + str((carry+int(S[-1]) + int(T[-1]))% 2)
    if S[-1] + T[-1]+carry==1:
        return addBhelper(S[:-1],T[:-1],1) + str((carry+int(S[-1]) + int(T[-1])) % 2)
    if S[-1] + T[-1]+carry==2:
        return addBhelper(S[:-1],T[:-1],2) + str((carry+int(S[-1]) + int(T[-1])) % 2)
    if S[-1] + T[-1]+carry==3:
        return addBhelper(S[:-1],T[:-1],2) + str((carry+int(S[-1]) + int(T[-1])) % 2)
  return addBhelper(S,T,0)
```

---- updated to fix code formatting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a cleaner version that uses some Python syntactic sugar:

```
def add(a,b,c=0):
    if a == '' and b == '':
        return str(c)
    a = a or '0'
    b = b or '0'
    n = int(a[-1]) + int(b[-1]) + c
    return add(a[:-1],b[:-1],n//2) + str(n%2)
```

- Use default value of carry `c=0` to get rid of the inner function
- `a = a or '0'` sets `a` to `'0'` if it's `''`
- You forgot to convert string to integer before adding them
- `n//2` get the carry

Answer (score 0):

Let’s start with the first part, which is making sure the two strings are the same length.  Since they're numbers, all you have to do is '0' pad the shorter number

```
max_len = max(len(S), len(T))
# the more simple to understand way
while len(S) < max_len: S = '0' + S
while len(T) < max_len: T = '0' + T
# or you can use this python trickery
S = ('0' * (max_len - len(S))) + S
T = ('0' * (max_len - len(T))) + T
```

For the carries, your carries should be as follows:

```
For sum = 0, carry = 0
For sum = 1, carry = 0
For sum = 2, carry = 1
For sum = 3, carry = 1
```

Hope that helps,

Comment: Thanks but I have to use recursion and I'm not allowed to use any loops

Comment: The second version doesn’t use loops.